# Disable javascript linting for particular sources in Play2

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to port my web application to Play, but some of the 3rd party JavaScript files (I put them in app/assets) can't pass the linting without significant changes.

How do I either disable the lint for some files or disable it completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put those files under ''public'' instead of app/assets/javascripts then they won't be checked. It's a quick and dirty solution but works well.

Comment: It's not dirty, as long as you don't gonna to modify 3-rd party libs (which is dirty ;)), they can be placed anywhere, best on static CDN handled by some fast HTTP server

Comment: Problem is that I want to concat them with Uglify, this solution doesn't help me atleast, because of that.

Comment: Use sbt-web and perhaps sbt-uglify with customised Build.scala. More work but gets you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to change app/assets folder structure, you can comment out

> addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")

this line in **plugins.sbt** file